# how to get Hight and Width image javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
        function readImage(inputFiles,$input){
            if(inputFiles == undefined || inputFiles.length == 0) return;

            var inputFile = inputFiles[0];

            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.readAsDataURL(inputFile);

            reader.onload = function(event) {

                $input.attr("src", event.target.result);

            var image = new Image();
            image.src = event.target.result;
            image.onload = function() {
                console.log('height: ' + this.height); ** <=== this * **
                console.log('width: ' + this.width);   ** <=== and this * **
            };

            };
        }
```

how i can make them global var

```
console.log('height: ' + this.height);
console.log('width: ' + this.width);
```

i want when i load an image i can get the height and width from another function
like :

```
function getSize(){
  return this.height+'|'+this.width;
}
```

Comment: Just pass the `image` object to the function?

Comment: @Jack you mean var image = new Image(); set it out ?

Comment: I mean you'd call your `getSize()` and pass it the image. `getSize(image)`.

Comment: but i use FileReader to read image and view it

Comment: solved my problem by moving all code into :

           image.onload = function() {
               //put my code to get the height and width

                 console.log('height: ' + this.height);
                 console.log('width: ' + this.width); 
            };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the image size, by using the following line of code:

```
var image = document.getElementById ('image');
console.log (image.clientWidth + "x" + image.clientHeight)
```

[Sample code in fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/saulo/vsNQ7/1/)

Comment: thanks for answer i'm not getting the height and width form a loaded image to some DOM i'm reading image ad FileReader and load them into image tag so i want to get the height and width before load them into image tag

Comment: solved my problem by moving all code into :

           image.onload = function() {
               //put my code to get the height and width

                 console.log('height: ' + this.height);
                 console.log('width: ' + this.width); 
            };